# Проблема с построением ссылки STEAM API

Tags: javascript, api, steam

Когда я искал возможности получения цены предмета Steam, то наткнулся на [тему на Hubr](https://qna.habr.com/q/265973), где был упомянут API Steam. Там была предоставлена рабочая ссылка, чтобы узнать цену на Негев. Я попытался подставить в ссылку свои данные, но API Steam выдаёт мне ошибку. Рассмотрим на примере предмета из CS:GO `Karambit | Autotronic (Factory New)`

```
const app_id = '730'
const country_code = 'us'
const currency_id = '1'
var item_type = 'Karambit'
var item_name = 'Autotronic'
var item_quality = 'Factory New'
var market_hash_name = (item_type.replace(' ','%20')+'%20%7C%20'+item_name.replace(' ','%20')+'%20%28'+item_quality.replace(' ','%20')+'%29)
var url = window.location.protocol + '//steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=' + app_id + '&country=' + country_code + '&currency=' + currency_id + '&market_hash_name=' + market_hash_name;
```

Полученную ссылку я копирую и ввожу в браузере. В ответ получаю `{"success":false}`
Все переменные вроде бы подставлены правильно, но мне кажется, что ошибку steam API возвращает из-за неправильного `market_hash_name`.

Comment: В стиме этот предмет записан со зведочкой: ★, но даже если подставить её, то ничего не будет

Comment: А вы правильный `app_id` указываете?

Comment: Да, 730 ИД - ид CS:GO

Comment: Посмотрите на url - https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=5&country=us&appid=730&market_hash_name=Negev%20%7C%20Army%20Sheen%20(Minimal%20Wear)&format=json

Comment: Смотрел. Даже если данные от туда взять и поставить имя другого предмета туда, то выдаст ошибку

Comment: А где звездочка стоит? Найдите предмет без звездочки. Плюс, используйте функцию `encodeURI` для кодирования `market_hash_name`, не надо вручную его создавать.